# Identify if an upsert operation inserts or updates the row in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Is there a way to identify if an upsert operation like the one shown below, inserts or either updates the row e.g., with the Java or Golang driver?

```
UPDATE test set value = 'value1', checkpoint = 'cas1' WHERE key = 'key1' IF checkpoint = '' OR NOT EXISTS;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RETURNS STATUS AS ROW as documented here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/api/ycql/dml_update/#returns-status-as-row 2
Example:

```
cqlsh:sample> CREATE TABLE test(h INT, r INT, v LIST<INT>, PRIMARY KEY(h,r)) WITH transactions={'enabled': true};
cqlsh:sample> INSERT INTO test(h,r,v) VALUES (1,1,[1,2]);
```

Unapplied update when IF condition is false:

```
cqlsh:sample> UPDATE test SET v[2] = 4 WHERE h = 1 AND r = 1 IF v[1] = 3 RETURNS STATUS AS ROW;

[applied] | [message] | h | r | v

-----------+-----------+---+---+--------

    False |      null | 1 | 1 | [1, 2]
```

Applied update when IF condition true:

```
cqlsh:sample> UPDATE test SET v[0] = 4 WHERE h = 1 AND r = 1 IF v[1] = 2 RETURNS STATUS AS ROW;
[applied] | [message] | h    | r    | v
-----------+-----------+------+------+------
     True |      null | null | null | null
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RETURNS STATUS AS ROW` is a YCQL feature. In YSQL, you could use an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE... EACH ROW` trigger to detect the outcome. The challenge, then, would be to surfcae the result in the session that made the change. You could use a user-defined run-time parameter (*set my_app.outcome = 'true'*) or a temp table.

*—regards, bryn@yugabyte.com*